# Exception Report from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, exception

**Background:**

The following function takes a pandas DataFrame and renames it `exceptions_df` whilst applying 2x conditions to it.

**Function:**

```
def ownership_exception_report():
    df = ownership_qc()
    exceptions_df = df[df['Entity ID %'] != 100.00]
    exceptions_df = df[df['Account # %'] != 100.00]
    return exceptions_df
```

**My problem:**
Whilst my code works fine, I wonder if there is a simple and more eloquent way to apply 2x conditions to a DataFrame and resave it? At the moment I am simply resaving the `exceptions_df` twice and it seems rather messy. Or perhaps I am wrong, and this is the correct way to apply conditions to a DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def ownership_exception_report():
    df = ownership_qc()
    return df[(df['Entity ID %'] != 100.00) & (df['Account # %'] != 100.00)]
```

Or:

```
def ownership_exception_report():
    df = ownership_qc()
    return df[df['Entity ID %'].ne(100.00) & df['Account # %'].ne(100.00)]
```

Both will return a copy of `df` with only the rows where `Entity ID %` is `100` AND `Account # %` is `100`.